# Where are default shared preferences written to?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, default-value

I am trying to initialise default shared preferences upon first run of my app. I found out that depending on how I do it, there are differences in the shared preferences file on the Android file system.

If I specifically write to the shared preferences with the following code, the XML file resides within /data/data/myapp/shared_prefs/:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
if ((myKey = pref.getString("key", null)) == null) {
  myKey = "default value";
  editor.putString("key", myKey );
  editor.commit();
}
```

However, if I use the following one-liner to initialize the default value, I don't see the XML file in /data/data/myapp/shared_prefs/:

```
myKey = pref.getString("key", "default value");
```

In the latter case, where is the XML file stored, and why is there a difference in behaviour?

Comment: In the latter case, nothing is being written. Unless you've previously written something to that same `SharedPreferences`, you shouldn't expect to see a file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll address your second case first:

> ```
> myKey = pref.getString("key", "default value");
> ```

What you're saying here is "get the value associated with `"key"`, or `"default value"` if nothing is". This is purely a *read* operation. When you get `"default value"` returned from this method, the system isn't actually "initializing" your shared preferences store, it's just saying "didn't find anything for `"key"`, so here's that other thing you said".

Next, your first case:

> ```
> SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
> if ((myKey = pref.getString("key", null)) == null) {
>     myKey = "default value";
>     editor.putString("key", myKey );
>     editor.commit();
> }
> ```

Here you do the same thing as above with regards to `getString()`, but this time you check its return value and then perform a *write* operation.  The body of your `if` block is what's creating the file.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that the second case would create a shared preference with the default value in addition to returning the default value. Clearly I was wrong. I guess the first case is the way to set a default value within the shared preference, unless there's a way to include the XML file directly into the Android Studio project?

Comment: you can simply use https://github.com/AliEsaAssadi/Android-Power-Preference